# unable to set image in JLabel

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I designed one simple Form.

In which i put one panel as contentPane one JLabel as lblPanel.

now i am trying to set image in JLabel.

I am having WindowBuilder so i can directly set image using setting the icon property of JLabel.

But when i try this it shows the Image only as its original size which is natural we must have to manually set image size to fed the JLabel whole.

SO, here is the Code that is generated by the WindowBuilder when i set the Image using the icon properties of JLabel.

```
lblPanel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Admin_Form.class.getResource("/Icons/MouthSmile.jpg")));
```

**Now My Problem is i want to set the size of image as the size of JLabel so there is any direct way to do it using WindowBuilder or just Modifying the above line?**

I also tried the following way in which i taken two Imageicon and one Image.

Here is the code for that that i have been tried.

```
private Image img;
private ImageIcon imgicon;
private ImageIcon newimgicon;

imgicon = new ImageIcon("/Icons/MouthSmile.jpg");
img = imgicon.getImage();

newimgicon = new ImageIcon(img.getScaledInstance(lblPanel.getWidth(),lblPanel.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)); 
lblPanel.setIcon(newimgicon);
```

But when i remove the code that is generated by the Window Builder and use only mine the image is not displayed.

I also seen the way to do it using BufferedImage but i think there will be no difference wheather i will use BufferedImage to resize or ImageIcon and Image.

Comment: The size of a JLabel containing an icon is the size of this icon. So if you resize the icon to the size of the JLabel before it has any icon inside, your image will be resized to 0. You should use your preferred image editing tool and resize the image to the dimension you want, and the JLabel will have the size of this icon. Moreover, the code generated to construct an ImageIcon is correct. Why do you modify it to `new ImageIcon("/Icons/MouthSmile.jpg")`, which is wrong?

Comment: can you elaborate what i am doing wrong here "Why do you modify it to new ImageIcon("/Icons/MouthSmile.jpg"), which is wrong?" because i am unable to understand.

Comment: You're loading the image from the file `/Icons/MouthSmile.jpg`, on the file system, which has 100% chance of not existing on the end user's desktop. Instead, you should load it with the class loader, from the classpath (and thus from the jar or directory of your application), just as the generated code does.

Comment: I modified my code first i set the size of JLabel in this case which is lblPanel then i put the image then also unable to set. And i also used getClass().getResources() to read file but still unable to set it.

Comment: Why do that at runtime? Resize your image to the appropriate size, put the resized image in your project, and voilà.

Comment: i used setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH); so the screen size may change there will be no effect and if i resize the image and then set it in different screen size it may not work properly. Am i Right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35658/discussion-between-google-and-jb-nizet)

Comment: @JBNizet i done it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the width and height of `lblPanel` before it is added to your `Container` and before your `JFrame` is visible, the width and height will both be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the image you are choosing to use which will make the JLabel the size you desire. That is the simplest way of going about doing it.